# How to Make a Typescript Reducer with Exact Generic Types

Tags: typescript, generics, reducers

### Problem

I have two reducers that use the exact same logic for two different arrays containing points. An array will only have points of a single type; these types are `A` and `B`. I want to create a reducer that accepts an array of points of type `A` or type `B` and then returns an array of that same type.

When I try to compile the code below, I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'Partial<A> | Partial<B>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<T>'.
  Type 'Partial<A>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.
```

**How can I fix this?**

### Problematic Code

```
enum Category {
  A,
  B
}

interface A  {
  readonly category: Category.A;
}
interface B  {
  readonly category: Category.B;
}

Category = 

const genericReducer = <T extends A | B>(
  state: MyState,
  action: Actions,
  points: T[],
  category: Category
): T[] => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POINT_UPDATED: {
      if (action.payload.category !== category) return points;

      return updateItemInArray(points, action.payload.id, (stpt) => {
        return updateObject(stpt, action.payload.newValues);
      });
    }

    default:
      return points;
  }
};
```

### ArrayUtils.updateObject

For reference, here is the `updateObject` function:

```
static updateObject = <T>(oldObject: T, newValues: Partial<T>) => {
    // Encapsulate the idea of passing a new object as the first parameter
    // to Object.assign to ensure we correctly copy data instead of mutating
    return Object.assign({}, oldObject, newValues);
};
```

### updateItemInArray Function

```
static updateItemInArray = <T>(array: T[], itemId: string, updateItemCallback: (item: T) => T): T[] => {
    const updatedItems = array.map((item) => {
      if (item.id !== itemId) {
        // Since we only want to update one item, preserve all others as they are now
        return item;
      }

      // Use the provided callback to create an updated item
      const updatedItem = updateItemCallback(item);
      return updatedItem;
    });

    return updatedItems;
};
```

### EDIT #1

Here is a CodeSandbox link to my latest attempt based on Linda Paiste's answer. At this time there is still an issue assigning to type `Partial<T>`.

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ss67l)

Comment: The problem is likely in your `updateItemInArray` function.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I edited my post to show `updateItemInArray`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Please provide type definition for `Actions`. I'm pretty sure this is the cause of the problem, because `action.payload.newValues` is of type `A | B` and `updateObject` expects type `Partial<T>` where `T extends A | B`. If `T extends A | B` it doesn't mean that `A | B` is assignable to it

Comment: @captain-yossarian Please see Edit #1 for a TS playground link.

Comment: @captain-yossarian  For some reason TS Playground cut off the majority of my code. I have attached a CodeSandbox link instead.

Comment: @RouteMapper. Thanks. I believe Linda Paiste will figure it out

Comment: @captain-yossarian I have no doubt Linda can. I'm fairly new to TS and I am amazed how she filled in the gaps. I should have just supplied a CodeSandbox example with all the code from the start.

Comment: @RouteMapper, it is true. The question with codesandbox examples will be answered much faster than question without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started trying to fill in the missing pieces of your code in order to find where the problem is.  Doing that, it became apparent that the issue is in your `Action` type (as suggested by @Alex Chashin).

I know that `Actions` has a `type` which needs to include `POINT_UPDATED`.  It also has a `payload`.  The payload includes an `id`, a `category`, and some `newValues`.

```
type Actions = {
    type: typeof POINT_UPDATED;
    payload: {
        id: string;
        category: Category;
        newValues: ????;
    }
}
```

What is `newValues`?  Based on the signature of `updateObject`, we know that it should be `Partial<T>`.  **But `Actions` doesn't know what `T` is.**

I'm guessing that your code uses something like `newValues: A | B;`, which gives me the error that you posted.  This is not specific enough.  It's not enough to know that our new values are "`A` or `B`".  `updateObject` says that if `T` is `A` then `newValues` must be `A` and if `T` is `B` then newValues must be `B`.

Therefore your `Actions` needs to be a generic type.

```
type Actions<T> = {
    type: typeof POINT_UPDATED;
    payload: {
        id: string;
        category: Category;
        newValues: Partial<T>;
    }
}

const genericReducer = <T extends A | B>(
  state: MyState,
  action: Actions<T>,
  points: T[],
  category: Category
): T[]
...
```

---

I'm seeing an error on your `updateItemInArray` when trying to access `item.id`:

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'T'

You need to refine the type of `T` such it knows about the id property:

```
const updateItemInArray = <T extends {id: string}>(
```

Doing this causes new errors in your `genericReducer` because you have said that `T` must have a `category` but you haven't said that it must have an `id`.  We can fix that with:

```
const genericReducer = <T extends (A | B) & {id: string}>(
```

which is the same as

```
const genericReducer = <T extends {id: string; category: Category}>(
```

Though it actually appears that you are never looking at the `category` on your points `T[]`.  So all you really need is:

```
const genericReducer = <T extends {id: string}>(
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Rd-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-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-0YbYOkDffBfDiF+MFBQxhtDFEGFiWXCA0jZHyPUYAjJgjbqeQej3FoNiQzrhDFwXc8VgCII8eElJuCu4sDYEAA)

---

Edit:

The error that you are getting in your revised code is honestly really dumb.  *Technically* `T` **`extends`** a type with `{elevation: number}`.  So there is the potential that it could require a more specific version of the type, like `{elevation: 99}`.  In that particular case, `{elevation: number}` would not be assignable to `Partial<{elevation: 99}>`.

At least I *thought* that was the problem.  However my first fix did not work.  I tried to refine the type of `Actions` to say that the `elevation` property must match the one from `T`.

```
type Payload<T extends A_or_B> = {
  [ActionTypes.FETCH_SUCCEEDED]: {
    id: string;
    elevation: T['elevation'];
    timestamp: number;
  };
...
```

But I'm still getting an error, so now I'm thoroughly confused.

> Argument of type `{ elevation: T["elevation"]; }` is not assignable to parameter of type `Partial<T>`

I really can't explain that one.

You might have to make an assertion instead. (Don't bother with the fix above).

```
return updateObject<{elevation: number}>(stpt, {
   elevation: action.payload.elevation,
}) as T;
```

We avoid errors within the `updateObject` function by setting the generic `T` of that function to `{elevation: number}`. Both `stpt` (type `T`) and `{elevation: number}` are assignable to that type.

But now the return type of the `updateObject` function is `{elevation: number}` instead of `T`.  So we need to assert `as T` in order to change the type.

Comment: Nice explanation, step by step

Comment: @Linda Paise Thank you! I no longer see a problem with my `POINT_UPDATED` action. However, I have added an additional action and it is still problematic. I added a TS Playground link as an edit to my original post. If you get a chance, can you take a look at it?

Comment: @Linda Paise For some reason TS Playground cut off the majority of my code. I have attached a CodeSandbox link instead.

Comment: Casting `as T` feels wrong but I suppose it'll have to do. I understand your explanation from your edit. Thanks.